# Git: Pick feature from Test version to Production version

Tags: git

I need help figuring out the branches that need to be created in git. Two developers working on two different features. A test version is needed to test both features. If only one of the features is required for the production version, how would you create the branches in git so that only one of feature is merged to master which is what is compile for the production version? How would you remove the feature from the test version that was dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd set up a Git repo with the following branches:

- master
- feature/feature-1
- feature/feature-2
- test

Developer 1 pushes changes to feature/feature-1, and Developer pushes changes to feature/feature-2. The test branch can be the feature branches merged together, along with test code. When you're ready, you can then merge feature/feature-1 into master, and then feature/feature-2 later on, if desired.